# Person/Group Lookup Field in Custom List custom new/edit form

Tags: lookup-column

In my Custom Newform.aspx I need a field that gives me the possibilty to insert a person or group known in the AD. 
How can I do this? Probably a kind of javascript or something like that.

It would be great, if it would behave like the control in sharepoint everybody knows from setting an administrator to a sitecollection.
Has somebody got a solution for my problem?

Thanks in Advance
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are working with Custom List, every Column in that list has a data type associated with it. If you specify "Person or Group" data type for your custom field, SharePoint will automatically display the people picker control.

Comment: Works great. Such a simple answer made my day:)

Comment: Glad to help you.. Good Luck!